# Pygame loading data in background

Tags: python, pygame

I have been building a lumines clone (tetris with music... kinda). I'd like to be able to load music and images in the background in order to reduce the memory footprint and to reduce initial loading times. Is there a way to go about this in pygame?

Comment: You can wait to load the image/sound until it's first requested. That probably will work fast enough.

Comment: It won't, because I transition between music and images when a certain number of points has been reached or a certain number of time. The ideal would be to load it in the background so there is no delay when playing.

Answer (score 0):

You can load all of the images in the background by blitting them underneath the others. This may make framerate worse (depending on the computer and other things) but will load all of the images. When you want a new one, just blit it last.

A code snippet:

```
if level == 1:
    screen.blit(image3, (0, 0))
    screen.blit(image2, (0, 0))
    screen.blit(image, (0, 0))
if level == 2:
    screen.blit(image, (0, 0))
    screen.blit(image3, (0, 0))
    screen.blit(image2, (0, 0))
```

that will, in the first level, blit "image" last, so "image will be the only one displayed. In the second level, "image2" will be displayed.

Really though, it is faster to just load the desired media and nothing else. Nothing is faster than that.